# Função Filter VBA

Tags: excel-vba

Estou usando o código abaixo para verificar se um elemento consta numa matriz relacionada a um Range. Acontece que em alguns casos o resultado é `= 0` demonstrando que existe, porem não existe.

O que está errado? AO invés desta função deveria percorrer a matriz através de um *Loop*?

```
If UBound(Filter(canc, Pl.Cells(x, "b").Value, , vbBinaryCompare)) <> -1
```

Answer (score 1):

já fiz esse função de busca porém com LOOP usando FOR na Matriz.
Basta informar a palavra que deverá ser encontrada e a tabela na qual será realizada a busca.

```
Function LoopNaTabela(palavra As String, Tb)
Dim Dimenssao As Byte, i As Long, j As LongOn Error Resume Next
If IsError(UBound(Tb, 2)) Then Dimensao = 1 Else Dimensao = 2
On Error GoTo 0
Select Case Dimensao
    Case 2
        For i = LBound(Tb, 1) To UBound(Tb, 1)
            For j = LBound(Tb, 2) To UBound(Tb, 2)
                If Tb(i, j) = palavra Then LoopNaTabela = True: Exit Function
            Next j
        Next i
End Select
End Function
```

Nesse formato ele vai percorrer toda a matriz em busca da palavra especifica, nunca tive problemas de desempenho com ela.

Caso queira testar outras maneiras, nesse link: [Verificar palavra](https://br.ccm.net/faq/18627-vba-verificar-se-existe-um-valor-em-uma-variavel-matriz)

tem bastante conteúdo e exemplo sobre o tema